# Replace quotation marks (or: use << and >> as csquote like auto-quotes)

Tags: xetex, punctuation, csquotes

I use french quotation marks (`<<` and `>>`) in many documents. Is there any way I can define in the style file to replace all french quotation marks by english ones?

Furthermore I'd like to have english quotation marks no matter if I type `<<hello>>` or `"hello"`. Is this possible?

EDIT: I read about the package `csquotes` but did not manage to replace my french marks because it seems like only *single* characters are allowed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[]{english}

\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text]{Open Sans}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text]{Open Sans}
\setmonofont[]{Consolas}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,english=british]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\MakeAutoQuote{<}{>}

\begin{document}


"An example using normal quotes"

< Example >

<<Second Example using french quotes>>

``Should look like this''

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I make `<` and `>`as my AutoQuote Delimiters, the original Quotation Marks are treated like nested quotations. Any suggestions to work around this?

Comment: I added some information to your title, so you may get another answer. To increase the chance please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `\MakeOuterQuote` (and `\MakeInnerQuote`) you can define a *single* character such as `"` that is use for opening and closing quotes. With `\MakeAutoQuote` you must define two distinct characters, such as `>` and `<` for opening and closing. In the latter case `csquotes` can find the quotation level itself.

Here’s an example how to use `\MakeAutoQuote`. By default the output quotation marks ar set language depend, but that can be changed by options.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
    \MakeOuterQuote{"}
    \MakeAutoQuote{>}{<}

\begin{document}
>Test automatic outer and >inner< quotes<

"Test manual outer quotes"
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

It is impossible to use `>>` or `<<` as a delimiter since it must be a single character. So you may use the search and replace feature of your editor to change this …

Comment: Hmm... In that case I will replace it manually using the replace function. Thanks anyway

Comment: It could be possible to do something with active characters, but as far as I can see that would require a manual implementation and is out of `csquotes`’ scope.