# How to Temporarily Diable \MakeOuterQuote for the quiver Package?

Tags: commutative-diagrams, csquotes

In my preamble, I have

```
\usepackage[autostyle=false, style=english]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

This allows me to write "x" as if I am writing ``x'' in LaTeX.  However, this interferences with my attempt to draw commutative diagrams, because quiver makes use of the symbols " and '.  How can I temporarily disable the csquotes package during the parts of my code that are using quiver?

Here is a MWE, which does compile, but if you uncomment the two lines involving csquotes, then the thing does not compile.  Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,graphicx,bbm}

% *** Fonts and Graphics **********************************************
\usepackage{eufrak}     % preloaded by amsart(?) above %\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
%           *** FONTS  ***
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\renewcommand{\frak}{\mathfrak}         % Math Fraktur (= Gothic; % the old \frak is obsolete so reuse its name

% %             *** Quotation Marks ***
% \usepackage[autostyle=false, style=english]{csquotes}
% \MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{quiver}

\begin{document}
% https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsMyxbMCwwLCJcXG1hdGhjYWwgQihcXG1hdGhjYWwgWl8xKSJdLFsyLDAsIlxcbWF0aGNhbCBCKFxcbWF0aGNhbCBaXzIpIl0sWzEsMywiWzAsMV0iXSxbMCwxLCJoIl0sWzEsMiwiXFxmcmFrIExcXGNpcmMgaF57LTF9XFxpbiBcXG1hdGhzY3IgQihcXG1hdGhjYWwgWl8xKSJdLFswLDIsIlxcZnJha3tMfVxcaW4gXFxtYXRoc2NyIEIoXFxtYXRoY2FsIFpfMSkiLDJdXQ==
\[\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    {\mathcal B(\mathcal Z_1)} \&\& {\mathcal B(\mathcal Z_2)} \\
    \\
    \\
    \& {[0,1]}
    \arrow["h", from=1-1, to=1-3]
    \arrow["{\frak L\circ h^{-1}\in \mathscr B(\mathcal Z_1)}", from=1-3, to=4-2]
    \arrow["{\frak L\in \mathscr B(\mathcal Z_1)}"', from=1-1, to=4-2]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `csquotes` has `\DisableQuotes`/`\EnableQuotes` for this. But you may be better off with some other choice of active character for this, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472729/105447.