Automated quotation marks with "" symbol
I'm writing a document (in Spanish) but at some point I need to use a quotation in English. I must say that the use of "" symbol as quotation mark produce problems when compile
For example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
    
    \enquote{Español}
    
    "Esto es una cita en español"
    
    "a
    
    %"e  ---> This produces problem to compile
    
    "i 
    
    "o
    
    "u
    
    "letter"
    
    "- %Disappears
    
    "r
    
    "y
    
\end{document}


However, if I use another word processor (Word, for example), I get

I'd really like to get the same result using Latex. Of course, I've used \AtBeginDocument{\shorthandoff{"}} and I got

This solves the problem partially, but note that that both quotation marks are right quotation marks.
Aditionally, only if possible, I would like to have "" interpreted according to the Spanish language and use angle quotes «», namely if in my code I use something like "This is a text", it produces «This is a text». I have seen other answers, but I think that they don't solve this problem. I have also used \selectlanguage{spanish} and \selectlanguage{english} but those are not working well or I don't understand how use them properly
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\AtBeginDocument{\shorthandoff{"}} 

\begin{document}
    
    %Text in spanish with angle quotes «»
    \selectlanguage{spanish}
    \enquote{Esto es una cita en español.}
    
    "Esto es una cita en español."
    
    \textquote{Esto es una cita en español.}
    
    \vspace{5pt}
    
    \hrule
    
    \vspace{5pt}
    
    %Text in English with English double quotes“”
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \enquote{This is a quotation in English.}
    
    "This is a quotation in English."
    
    \textquote{This is a quotation in English.}
    
\end{document}


Thank you very much if you have read this far and I would appreciate so much your help. Thanks in advance c:

This doesn't satisfy all your desiderata. TeX is not a word processor but a mark-up language. As such, things work differently and that has both advantages and disadvantages. In some cases, the same difference is both an advantage and a disadvantage of one versus the other.
You need autostyle to tell csquotes to adapt to the current language. If you are using a non-Unicode engine (e.g. pdfTeX), you should uncomment fontenc because the default encoding doesn't support Spanish adequately. (I would do this even for English as the default encoding has no advantages to speak of and several disadvantages.)
You will then get the correct quotes with \enquote{} and \textquote{}. You can also define active 'auto' quotation marks, which are like \enquote{}. These are nesting-sensitive so do the right thing (like \enquote{} etc.) even when a quotation contains a quotation containing a quotation.
If you want to define auto quotes, \MakeAutoQuote{<opening>}{<closing>} is the basic command. The starred version defines marks for selecting the inner quotation style directly.
The characters you choose for active quotation marks need to be chosen somewhat carefully. In particular, the opening and closing mark must be different, so you cannot use "...". I like to use actual opening and closing curly quotation marks, but I write in languages which use this form and you may obviously prefer something else. The main problem is then to configure your editor so you can easily produce the required marks.
The standard way to produce opening and closing quotation marks in English is
`single'; ``double''
but that is obviously not language-sensitive. In the example below, for instance, note that this does the wrong thing in Spanish.
\documentclass[american,spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
\MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}
% \AtBeginDocument{\shorthandoff{"}}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%Text in spanish with angle quotes «»
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\enquote{Esto es una cita en español.}

``Esto es una cita en español.''

\textquote{Esto es una cita en español.}

‘Esto es una cita en español.’
\bigskip

\hrule

\bigskip

%Text in English with English double quotes“”
\selectlanguage{american}
\enquote{This is a quotation in English.}

``This is a quotation in English.''

\textquote{This is a quotation in English.}

‘This is a quotation in English containing a quoted ‘x’.’

\end{document}



" is viable with \MakeOuterQuote, though certainly a bad idea with babel spanish... For the choice of quote character, this is my go-to reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472729/105447, which may be useful to the OP.

@gusbrs but you need two distinct characters, so you'd need " and something else.

\MakeOuterQuote takes a single character as argument, and it works then for opening and closing (if it's open, closes, if it's closed, open). Probably, " is the quintessential value to be used there but, again, bad idea for languages which make it active.

Or, to be fairer, not a great idea regardless and probably only useful if you have a really lousy editor.  ;-)

@gusbrs yes, I realised this right after I left this tab, but have only just managed to find it again. (I have rather a lot of open tabs.) sorry.

@gusbrs and you'd have to think about whether you might later want to change the quote to inner. what's nice about the auto marks is you don't have to know that.

Yes, my normal setting is \MakeAutoQuote{“}{”} only, no starred version, as discussed in the "Coda" of that link.
